# How to make use of the "Stack Snippets" more intuitive to new users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

I noticed that some users are using the [*Stack Snippets*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for `ruby`, `vb`, `java`, `php` and other "things", even though implicit in the text fields the words `html`, `css` and `javascript`.

I suggested:

- Change the icon to something more intuitive:

  [image: icon]
- (If possible) *Stack Snippets* is allowed for questions with [html](/questions/tagged/html), [css](/questions/tagged/css), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tags.
- Show an alert if added something other than [html](/questions/tagged/html)/[css](/questions/tagged/css)/[js](/questions/tagged/js).

I really do not know why they use the *Stack Snippets* in the wrong way, which can be? And how to make the most intuitive use?

Example of problem:

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28078420/1

Comment: And C/C++, and C#, and, and, and... it could be made clearer that "snippet" stands for "executable JavaScript". I like option 2 / only enable the button when there's a JavaScript tag.