# Add option to search posts with 'Stack Snippets'

Tags: feature-request, search, stack-snippets

Read this first: [How to make use of the "Stack Snippets" more intuitive to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247424/198279)

Clearly is a problem that will not be resolved anytime soon, but I have a suggestion that may *help to make our lives easier*:

In **Advanced Search** add a new feature (option/query) like this:

```
with:stacksnippets
```

Resulting in a link like this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3635+with%3Astacksnippets

This option returning all posts with *stack snippet* in body, eg.:

- Return questions about PHP using the *stack snippets* unnecessarily `[php] is:question with:stacksnippets`:

  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+is%3Aquestion+with%3Astacksnippets

The reason for this need is that I take several minutes looking for questions that use stacksnippets unnecessarily.  I want to edit them to better organize the community, but usually my research is not efficient.

Comment: Consider also supporting `with:image`, then.